# Global Token interceptor callback kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I am currently building a Jetpack compose app that utilizes Authorization token and does a Token refresh. Issue I have now is that when the token refresh fails, I want to send user back to login page because the refresh expired. I have created a callback and tried handling it like this

```
interface TokenRefreshErrorCallback {
    fun onTokenRefreshError()
}
class TokenInterceptor @Inject constructor(
    private val tokenManager: TokenManager,
    private val userLocalRepository: UserLocalRepository,
    private val tokenRefreshErrorCallback: TokenRefreshErrorCallback
) : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val originalRequest = chain.request()
        val token = tokenManager.getToken()

        if (token != null) {
            if (!tokenManager.isAccessTokenValid()) {
                // Make the token refresh request
                val refreshedToken = runBlocking {
                    val user = userLocalRepository.get()
                    if (user != null) {
                        try {
                            val response = tokenManager.refreshToken(
                                request = RefreshTokenRequest(
                                    user = user.id,
                                    token = token.refreshToken,
                                    role = "user"
                                )
                            )
                            response.data?.let { tokenManager.updateToken(token = it) }
                            response.data

                        } catch (throwable: Exception) {
                            val message = when (throwable) {
                                is HttpException -> throwable.toErrorMessage()
                                else -> throwable.localizedMessage
                            }
                            Log.d("ERROR tokenManager::", message)
                            // Notify the callback about the token refresh error
                            tokenRefreshErrorCallback.onTokenRefreshError()
                            null
                        }

                        // Update the refreshed access token and its expiration time in the session

                    } else null
                }

                if (refreshedToken != null) {
                    // Create a new request with the refreshed access token
                    val newRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("x-build-number", "${BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE}")
                        .header("Authorization", "Bearer ${refreshedToken.accessToken}")
                        .build()

                    // Retry the request with the new access token
                    return chain.proceed(newRequest)
                }
            }
        }

        // Add the access token to the request header
        val authorizedRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
            .addHeader("x-build-number", "${BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE}")
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer ${token?.accessToken ?: ""}")
            .build()

        return chain.proceed(authorizedRequest)
    }
}

class TokenManager @Inject constructor(
    private val sharedPreferenceManager: SharedPreferenceManager,
    private val tokenRefreshApi: TokenRefreshApi
) {

    fun isAccessTokenValid(): Boolean {
        return sharedPreferenceManager.getToken() != null && sharedPreferenceManager.getToken()!!.isValid
    }

    fun updateToken(token: UserToken) {
        sharedPreferenceManager.setToken(token = token)
    }

    fun getToken(): UserToken? {
        return sharedPreferenceManager.getToken()
    }

    suspend fun refreshToken(request: RefreshTokenRequest): BaseResponse<UserToken> {
        return tokenRefreshApi.refreshToken(request)
    }
}
```

My injector is like this

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideTokenManager(
    tokenRefreshApi: TokenRefreshApi,
    sharedPreferences: SharedPreferenceManager
) = TokenManager(
    tokenRefreshApi =  tokenRefreshApi,
    sharedPreferenceManager = sharedPreferences)

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideTokenRefreshErrorCallback(): TokenRefreshErrorCallback {
    return object : TokenRefreshErrorCallback {
        override fun onTokenRefreshError() {
            // Handle the token refresh error callback
        }
    }
}

OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .readTimeout(REQUEST_TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .connectTimeout(REQUEST_TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .addInterceptor(tokenInterceptor)
    .addInterceptor(UserAgentInterceptor())
    .build()
```

I am then using it in my Main app like

```
fun AppNavigation() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val authenticationDataViewModel: AuthenticationDataViewModel = viewModel()
    val mainViewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel()

    val logoutEvent = mainViewModel.logoutEvent.observeAsState()
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Screen.Splash.route
    ) {

        composable(Screen.Splash.route) {
            SplashView(navController = navController)
        }

        composable(route = Screen.Base.route) {
            TabBarView(onLogout = { onLogout(navController) })
        }

        composable(Screen.Landing.route) {
            LandingPageView(navController = navController)
        }
    }

    DisposableEffect(logoutEvent.value) {
        if (logoutEvent.value != null) {
            onLogout(navController)
        }
        onDispose {
            // Cleanup logic if needed
        }
    }
}

@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
): ViewModel(), TokenRefreshErrorCallback {

    private val _isAuthenticated = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val isAuthenticated: LiveData<Boolean> get() = _isAuthenticated

    // LiveData for logout event
    private val _logoutEvent = MutableLiveData<Unit>()
    val logoutEvent: LiveData<Unit> get() = _logoutEvent
    override fun onTokenRefreshError() {
        Log.d("LOGOUT CALLBACK", "CALLEDDDDDDDDD")
        _isAuthenticated.value = false

        // Trigger the logout event
        _logoutEvent.value = Unit
        logout()
    }

    private fun logout() {
        _isAuthenticated.value = false
    }
}
```

My `onTokenRefreshError` is never called. No matter how much I change it.

I am also relatively new to android and coming from iOS where we have a Notification Center to actually send a broadcast .

Comment: Use field injector to create a variable of TokenRefreshErrorCallback in your viewModel instead of implementing this interface. Ex. @inject lateinit var callback : TokenRefreshErrorCallback and use it's overridden method.

Comment: Also, field injection might not be the recommended approach for ViewModels due to their lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

With Hilt, `TokenInterceptor` will use `TokenRefreshErrorCallback` created by your `provideTokenRefreshErrorCallback`, not view model that implements it(looks like that's what you expect).

To solve this you need some object that will pass event from `TokenInterceptor` to your view model.

You can create a separate object, or use `TokenManager` for this purpose. Instead of callback, you can create a flow - you'll pass an event there, and collect it in view model.

I don't have experience with live data, not sure how it should be collected in Compose - with flow it's easy to do with `LaunchedEffect`, if your project is not big I would recommend you migrating to flows.

This is how I could've done it with flow:

```
class TokenManager @Inject constructor(
    private val sharedPreferenceManager: SharedPreferenceManager,
    private val tokenRefreshApi: TokenRefreshApi
) {
    private val _logoutEvent = MutableSharedFlow<Unit>()
    val logoutEvent = _logoutEvent.asSharedFlow()

    fun onLogout() {
        logoutEvent.emit(Unit)
    }
```

```
class TokenInterceptor @Inject constructor(
    private val tokenManager: TokenManager,
    private val userLocalRepository: UserLocalRepository,
    private val tokenRefreshErrorCallback: TokenRefreshErrorCallback
) : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        // Notify the callback about the token refresh error
        tokenManager.onLogout()
```

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    val tokenManager: TokenManager
): ViewModel() {
    val logoutEvent = tokenManager.logoutEvent
```

And then collect it in the view:

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    mainViewModel.logoutEvent.collect {
        onLogout(navController)
    }
}
```